# Errror Al Guardar filas en DataGridView a Base De Datos

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buenas Estoy Haciendo Ingresos De Productos En Modelo En capas Esta Es Mi Entidad[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta Es Mi Capa DAl[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8ddW.png)

cargar producto en el dataview[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

boton + [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
boton guardar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla detalleingreso
 [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al momento de guardar
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

salta este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error te lo esta diciendo ahi esta tratando de convertir ese texto en un Entero,Podrias poner tu sp igual para ver

Comment: iF EXISTS (SELECT NAME FROM sys.procedures WHERE NAME = 'AgregarDetalleIngreso')
  Begin 
      Print 'El Procedimiento AgregarDetalleIngreso >>Ya Existe<<'
  End
 Go 
   Create Procedure AgregarDetalleIngreso     
      (
   IdIngreso int,
   IdInsumos int,
   Insumos   char (40),
   Stock     int  
   )             
      As 
  Begin 
      insert into DetalleIngreso values
   (
   IdIngreso,
   IdInsumos,
   Stock,
   Insumos
   )
  End                         quite los @ porque no me dejaba publicarlos

Comment: Edita la respuesta y agregalo ahi saludos

Comment: podrias editar la pregunta y poner el codigo como texto en lugar de imagenes

Comment: intentas pasar un string a un campo que has declarado como int. Al hacer el insert tampoco le pasas los parametros correctos ya que le tienes que pasar el Id que no se lo pasas. Para arreglar todo (creo) deberías declarar el Id como autonumérico y al pasarle los 4 parámetros que le envías, el string "salchicha" ya se guardaría en Insumos y te dejará de dar el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta en el procedure, debes definir las columnas en el insert para definir como mapea el parametro con la columna

```
 Create Procedure AgregarDetalleIngreso ( 
     @IdIngreso int, 
     @IdInsumos int, 
     @Insumos char(40), 
     @Stock int) As 
 Begin

       insert into DetalleIngreso (IdIngresos, IdInsumos, Stock, Insumos) 
       values ( @IdIngreso, @IdInsumos, @Stock, @Insumos)

 End
```

Pero ademas no respectas los tipos de datos

Si analizas las columnas de la tabla veras que los campos `IdIngreso`, `IdInsumo` y `Stock` son del tipo `int`

Mientras que en la clase defines las propiedades `IdIngreso`, `IdInsumo` y `Stock` como `string`

La idea es que se respecten los tipos de datos para evitar problemas

Comment: el error me lo resalta en el campo insumos a que valor tiene que cambiar para poder tomarlo en la entidad y en el boton guardar

Comment: como que resalta el error? por lo que entendia el codigo compilaba, pero fallaba al realizar el ExecuteNonQuery(). El campo Insumos es un string, lo que tienes que cambiar es el procedure

Comment: me resalto error el procedimiento que pusiste quite el begin y esta compilando gracias

Comment: que raro porque tome el procedure que pusiste en el comentario como base para agregar los campos en el insert y alli usas el begin, pero bueno creo que igual la idea que queria transmitir quedaba clara. Debes definir los campos en el insert para que se aliñen con el orden de los parametro